# How to access the object you instantiated or set a limit for spawnable objects unity 3d

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Im stuck in a problem that I have, I made a script that makes objects, simple script no addons.
But I want to set a limit on how much enemies there can be at once (because its laggy)
I have absolutely no idea how, any help appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's bunch of ways to do that, but the most simple one is to declare a GameObject\Transform\your enherit from monobehavior collection in that script:

```
private List<GameObject> _entities;
```

And then you add it from Instantiate method, like this:

```
_entities.Add(Instantiate(*your prefab and other parameters*));
```

Instantiate() method returns you instatiated GameObject

and setting the limit here should be fairly easy as well:

```
 if (_entities.Count < _entitiesLimit)
 {
      _entities.Add(Instatiate(_prefab));
 }
```

Comment: I did not understand anything but ill test it out ty

Comment: Thanks it works but for me the enemies have hp and when hp = 0 the object destroys but the script thinks the list still has 5 items, it does but it says missing prefabs, how to check the prefs that are missing and delete them (list) ty!

Comment: You can try to remove it from that list
In the enemy's script in 
void OnDestroy(){

}

try to access spawner's List through some kind of method and use _entities.Remove(entity);

Comment: enemy's script should contain

*YourSpawnersType* _spawner;
void OnDestroy()
{
      _spawner.RemoveEnemy(this);
}


in spawner's script

public void RemoveEnemy(Enemy entity)
{
     _entities.Remove(entity);
}

Comment: I used List.RemoveAll(x => !x);

Answer (score 1):

One relatively simple approach is to create a manager script that handles the spawning.  It can internally track the number of spawned objects and then just not spawn the objects once the maximum number has been reached.

This sounds like you might want an object pool, which is built into Unity 2021 (https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Pool.ObjectPool_1.html).

Here's a little object pool that I wrote to handle  a similar situation:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class ObjectPool<T>
{
    public delegate T OnCreate();
    public delegate void OnGet(T obj);
    public delegate void OnRelease(T obj);

    Stack<T> _objects;
    OnCreate _onCreate;
    OnGet _onGet;
    OnRelease _onRelease;

    public ObjectPool(OnCreate onCreate, OnGet onGet, OnRelease onRelease)
    {
        _objects = new Stack<T>();
        _onCreate = onCreate;
        _onGet = onGet;
        _onRelease = onRelease;
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        T obj;
        obj = _objects.Count == 0 ? _onCreate() : _objects.Pop();

        _onGet(obj);
        return obj;
    }

    public void Release(T obj)
    {
        _onRelease(obj);
        _objects.Push(obj);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _objects.Clear();
    }
}
```

Rather than destroying the objects, you Release() them to the pool so they can be reused later.  The onCreate, onGet, and onRelease delegates are just generic ways to make sure that whatever initialization and disabling needs to happen to the game objects when you get or release them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).